# AspectJ custom parameter annotation not working in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, aspectj

I'm trying to create a custom annotation called `@ValidDate` to check if a given Date object is not older than one week.

This is the annotation definition.

```
package com.verimi.kitchenservice.annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
public @interface ValidDate {
    
}
```

Here is the AspectJ behavior definition class.

```
package com.verimi.kitchenservice.validators;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class DateValidator {

    @Before(value = "@annotation(com.verimi.kitchenservice.annotations.ValidDate)")
    public Object before(JoinPoint parameter) {

        System.out.println( "called here" + parameter.toString() );
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is the usage in my RestController:

```
@GetMapping("/week_plan")
public List<DayOfService> all(@RequestParam("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") @ValidDate Date requestedDate) {

    List<DayOfService> dayOfServiceList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

My System.out.println is not being called. When I changed the aspect as follows it hits the System.out.println line from the start up Spring Boot.

```
@Before("execution(* *(..))")
```

If it works as above, why not work for `@annotation`?

I also have the following dependency as well:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I have notice that you are annotation the parameter not the method, can you try to annotate a method to see if it would work?

Comment: I am under the impression that this is not possible for parameters but don't quote on this

Comment: @dreamcrash Voila! It works when I move the annotation to the method level. **But why it is not possible to have it as parameter annotation? It makes more sense to have it as a parameter level.**

Comment: I think it is just a limitation of AspectJ

Comment: Why don't you use Bean Validation that will support this out of the box

Comment: @SimonMartinelli can you demonstrate it as an example? I'm quite new to AspectJ

Comment: @JudeNiroshan This seams to be an spring feature rather than AspectJ

Comment: What should ValidDate validate? A date range?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I need to validate a given date falls within the last week only. If not API should return BAD_REQUEST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to add the validation starter to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Next you must create your own validation annotation:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = DateValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidDate {

    String message() default "Date is not of last week";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Then you need a validator:

```
public class DateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidDate, LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(LocalDate value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return dateIsOfLastWeek(value);
    }

    private boolean dateIsOfLastWeek(LocalDate value) {
        return value.isAfter(LocalDate.now().plusDays(7)) && value.isBefore(LocalDate.now());
    }
}
```

And finally you have to add the annotation to the controller:

```
@Validated // Will validate in this controller
@RestController
public class ValidController {

    @GetMapping("validation")
    public String get(@RequestParam("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") @ValidDate LocalDate requestedDate) {
        return "valid";
    }

    // The exception handler is need to return a status 400 instead of 500 
    // plus the message in the body of the response
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> onValidationError(Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very much appreciated your detailed answer.

Comment: The way to thank people on SO is to mark their answers as accepted. If your problem is still not solved, please explain so in a comment in order to motivate someone else to answer it.